# How to create a GET, POST, and PUT request in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, post, get, put

I can connect to a server synchronously with this code snippet in swift.

```
let URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://someserver.com)!
let InfoJSON: NSData? = NSData(contentsOfURL: URL)
let JsonInfo: NSString = NSString(data:InfoJSON!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
let GameListAttributions: NSArray = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(InfoJSON!, options: .allZeros, error: nil)! as NSArray
```

This is only good for receiving information all at once, but how would I use a GET, POST, and PUT with Swift. No matter how much I search I can't find a good tutorial or example on how to execute these.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
let url = NSURL(string: "https://yourUrl.com") //Remember to put ATS exception if the URL is not https
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url! as URL)
request.addValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type") //Optional
request.httpMethod = "PUT"
let session = URLSession(configuration:URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
let data = "username=self@gmail.com&password=password".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
request.httpBody = data

let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    if error != nil {

        //handle error
    }
    else {

        let jsonStr = NSString(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        print("Parsed JSON: '\(jsonStr)'")
    }
}
dataTask.resume()
```

*Recently updated for for Swift 5; thanks to the user [SqAR.org](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2960387/sqar-org)*

Answer (score 4):

I created a function for a project that with the correct arguments you can post , put and get

```
private func fetchData(feed:String,token:String? = nil,parameters:[String:AnyObject]? = nil,method:String? = nil, onCompletion:(success:Bool,data:NSDictionary?)->Void){

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = true

        let url = NSURL(string: feed)
        if let unwrapped_url = NSURL(string: feed){

            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: unwrapped_url)

            if let tk = token {
                let authValue = "Token \(tk)"
                request.setValue(authValue, forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            }

            if let parm = parameters{
                if let data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parm, options:NSJSONWritingOptions(0), error:nil) as NSData? {

                    //println(NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions(0), error: nil))
                    request.HTTPBody = data
                    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                    request.setValue("\(data.length)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
                }
            }

            if let unwrapped_method = method {
                request.HTTPMethod = unwrapped_method
            }

            let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
            sessionConfiguration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0
            let session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration)
            let taskGetCategories = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request){ (responseData, response, error) -> Void in



                let statusCode = (response as NSHTTPURLResponse?)?.statusCode
                //println("Status Code: \(statusCode), error: \(error)")
                if error != nil || (statusCode != 200 && statusCode != 201 && statusCode != 202){
                    onCompletion(success: false, data:nil)

                }
                else {
                    var e: NSError?
                    if let dictionary = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options: .MutableContainers | .AllowFragments, error: &e) as? NSDictionary{
                        onCompletion(success:true,data:dictionary)

                    }
                    else{
                        onCompletion(success: false, data:nil)
                    }
                }
            }

            UIApplication.sharedApplication().networkActivityIndicatorVisible = false
            taskGetCategories.resume()
        }
    }
}
```

This how to use the function:

```
    fetchData(feed,token: Constants.token(), parameters: params, method: "POST", onCompletion: { (success, data) -> Void in
            if success { //Code after completion} })
```

- feed -> This is the link to the server
- token (optional) -> Some requests needs token for security purposes
- parameters (optional) -> These are all the parameters you can pass to the server. (This is a dictionary btw)
- method (optional) -> Here you can choose what type of request you want ("GET","POST","PUT")
- completion closure -> Here you pass a function that is going to execute when the request is completed. In the closure you get two parameter: "success" is a bool that indicates if the request was successful and "data". This is a dictionary with all the response data.(it could be nil)

Hope i helped. And sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You can use the swift `NSMutableURLRequest` in order to make a POST request.

Swift GET Example:

```
let requestURL = NSURL(string:"urlhere")!

var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: requestURL)
request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler:loadedData)
task.resume()
```

**Documentation POST Example:**

```
NSString *bodyData = @"name=Jane+Doe&address=123+Main+St";

NSMutableURLRequest *postRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.apple.com"]];

// Set the request's content type to application/x-www-form-urlencoded
[postRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

// Designate the request a POST request and specify its body data
[postRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[postRequest setHTTPBody:[NSData dataWithBytes:[bodyData UTF8String] length:strlen([bodyData UTF8String])]];
```

This is in objective-c but easy enough to convert to swift.

**Documentation:**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001836-SW4

Answer (score -1):

Simple **Swift 5** GET request:

```
let params = "param1=something&param2=whatever".addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed)!
let task = URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://web.com/test.php?\(params)")!))
task.resume()
```