# How can I send a request to api.myjson.com with Swift and Xcode?

Tags: ios, ajax, json, swift, api

I am trying to update a JSON file from my iOS app in Swift. I do not want to write a separate JQuery script, since I do not have enough knowledge nor the time to do so. The JSON file is hosted at the myjson api at api.myjson.com Here they explain how to use the api: http://myjson.com/api

I understand that each method such as 'PUT' or 'POST' is appended to the end of the website, like api.myjson.com/example?type=PUT.

What I am trying to figure out is the syntax to add to or update my JSON files stored here.

Comment: "I understand that each method such as 'PUT' or 'POST' is appended to the end of the website, like api.myjson.com/example?type=PUT." — No. That is completely wrong. The HTTP method does not appear in the URL at all.

Comment: Then how can I update a json file without using JQuery?

Comment: The doc at http://myjson.com/api is quite clear:
Create a new JSON: type `POST`
Update a JSON: type `PUT`

Comment: @JonathanAllenGrant — I have no idea how whatever HTTP client library you are using in Swift expects you to tell it which HTTP method method to use. The documentation you link to gives an example of each raw HTTP method line.

Comment: Your question might actually be: "how can I send a request with swift to myjson.com/api"

Comment: I changed my title, do you know how I can do it?

Comment: @Quentin I do not see a raw HTTP method line. I only see raw JQuery code, can you post it here?

Comment: `GET /bins/:id` is the first one

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29360523/how-to-create-a-get-post-and-put-request-in-swift

Answer (score 0):

The url in .ajax() calls follows the exact same rules as an `href` or `src` in plain html would:

e.g you're on `http://example.com/dir/subdir/somescript.php`:

```
$.ajax('foo.php');    -> http://example.com/dir/subdir/foo.php
$.ajax('/foo.php);    -> http://example.com/foo.php
$.ajax('../foo.php'); -> http://example.com/dir/foo.php
```

The method used is generally `GET`, but you can specify whatever method you want in the options:

```
$.ajax(url, {method:"POST"});
```

Comment: The question is asking about how to make the requests with Swift/Unspecified-HTTP-library not JavaScript/jQuery